# How to finish this proof?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying prove the following:

If $F: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ are continuous and $g(t) = \int_{a}^t F(x,g(x)) dx$ then $g'(t)= F(t,g(t))$.

My idea is to use the definition of the derivative:
$$ g'(t) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} { g(t + \varepsilon) - g(t) \over \varepsilon} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} { \int_a^{t+\varepsilon} F(x,g(x)) dx- \int_a^t F(x,g(x)) dx \over \varepsilon} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} { \int_t^{t+\varepsilon} F(x,g(x)) dx \over \varepsilon}$$

Define $H(z) =  \int_a^{z} F(x,g(x)) dx$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus  $H$ is a continuous function $[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ and $H'(x) = F(x,g(x))$. Then:

$$  g'(t) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} {H(t + \varepsilon) - H(t) \over \varepsilon} = H'(t) = F(t,g(t))$$

Is it right?

Comment: Why does it not work? By the continuity you know that the integrand of the last integral is really close to $F(t,g(t))$ for small $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes but how can I use it? Now I have a new idea to use the fundamental theorem of calculus. I will add it in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And for the proof of the fundamental theorem, you use that the integrand is continuous at $t$ (it holds more generally, $t$ being a Lebesgue point of the integrand suffices).